# how to integrate my business with whatsup business api?

Tags: java, whatsapp

I am trying to integrate my business with whatsup business api.
Do I need to download, install business app and makes requests or I can use only business api?
If only business api is enough, how can i get the uri for which I can make requests.

I tried register my business, I didn't get any response for uri.
I am also unable to install business app.
I am getting the error:
docker-compose up -d
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "image" option in service "waweb": "docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v${WA_API_VERSION:?Run docker-compose with env var WA_API_VERSION (ex. WA_API_VERSION=2.21.4 docker-compose  )}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major ways for a business to use WhatsApp right now. If you're a small to medium scale business and can handle the traffic through an app you can use WhatsApp for Business app from the appstore. If you feel like you have more traffic and need programmatic access, then WhatsApp Business API is your thing. In order to use WhatsApp Business API you don't need to install any app. It comes as a set of docker images that you spin in an orchestration of your choice (docker, AWS, Kubernetes, etc.)

The [WhatsApp documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/getting-started) lists the required steps to get start with API.

1. You need to create a WhatsApp account for you business on Facebook Business Manager.
2. You need to register your phone numbers and get the certificate from Business Manager.
3. There are 2 docker images that you need for your setup which are publicly available (webapp and coreapp)
4. When you run the docker-compose up, you also need to setup the WA_API_VERSION environment to the version of the webapp/coreapp that you want to run. The latest versions can be found here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/changelog)